Program hangs while forking in a loop
I have made a program in C that uses fork() function in a loop and in the child process it executes another program with execlp(). The second program is used to listen for signals (for example CTRL+c, or from the console). The main program should wait for all child processes after the executed program finishes and display its exit status. However, I ran into some problems. The first iteration of loop works fine, but in the second one the program hangs forever and nothing could be done except terminating it. Here is the source code:
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int stat;
    pid_t pd;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        switch (pd = fork())
        {
            case -1:
                perror("fork error!");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                execlp("./sighandler", "./sighandler", argv[1], argv[2], (char *)NULL);
            default:
                if (wait(&stat) == -1) {
                    perror("wait error!");
                    exit(2);
                }
                printf("PID = %d | %d\n", pd, WEXITSTATUS(stat));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

The program should run the printf() function 5 times (the iterator count), wait for all child processes to finish and exit normally.

you're trying to wait for the child process within the loop, but after the first iteration, the child process created in the next iteration will be waiting for its own child process to finish, leading to a deadlock situation.

What is the code for sighandler?  What do the arguments do?  What values do you pass to the code you show?  You need to put error processing after the execlp() just in case something goes wrong — the code should print an error and exit.  For debugging multiple process scenarios, ensure that you print lots more information than you are printing, and include the current PID as the first argument in each print operation:  printf("%5d: …\n", getpid(), …);.  Note the newline at the end of the print.  I dislike perror() because it doesn't include things like the PID unless you work hard.

Related to the question of "What do the arguments to sighandler do?" — how do you terminate sighandler, or how does it terminate itself?

Side note: there is no point in using execlp() — or execvp() or any of the other exec*p*() functions — if the pathname of the command to be executed contains a  slash /.  The path lookup is nullified — you might as well use execl() or execv() etc.

Judging from my adapted, instrumented version of the code in the question, running a program that either doesn't exist or that works happily and exits, the code in the question is "OK".  It suggests the problem is in your sighandler program, the code for which you've not shown.  At any rate, I can't debug your problem until you provide the code for sighandler and an explanation of what the arguments to it do (or a much more detailed explanation of what it does, but the simplest way to provide that explanation is to provide the code).

The code in the question has problems if the execlp() fails — then you have two processes both thinking they're meant to run the loop.  OTOH, if the execlp() succeeds, then there is no problem.  The first comment is not a complete description of the behaviour of the code — it applies in an edge case (when execlp() fails and therefore returns).  Remember: when a member of the exec*() family of functions succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.
